# Cuda app over ssh

Tags: ssh, cuda, x11, x11-forwarding

I am trying running a cuda app written using cudamat (a python interface for cuda) over ssh. I don't understand why it only works if I connect with the "-X" option; If I don't, I get the message: "Unable to access the X Display, is $DISPLAY set properly?".

The main problem with this is that I would like to run it as a batch job. Could I avoid it asking for a X Display (since it doesn't really display anything...)? Or is it possible to create some kind of virtual display to make it shut up?

Comment: what modules do you import?

Comment: CUDA doesn't require an X11 connection and will run happily over a tty link via ssh to a headless remote machine. Whatever your problem is, it almost certainly doesn't have anything to do with CUDA.

Comment: Why do you say CUDA doesn't require an X11 connection? It uses the GPU so it makes sense it uses an X to connect to the graphics card, if only to query the GPU's capabilities. Of course then the trick is to let the app use the remote server's hardware, not your own...

Comment: @JvO CUDA does not require X.  Take a look at [this blog](http://www.resultsovercoffee.com/2011/01/cuda-in-runlevel-3.html), as just one of many possible proofs of this.

Comment: @JvO Because it doesn't. CUDA applications running on a given host only need access to the NVIDIA driver via the `/dev` filesystem. That doesn't require an X11 server. I use CUDA on a remote host every day  without a local or remote X11 server running.

Answer (score 1):

To partially answer your question: yes, you can create a virtual X server on the remote machine with Xvfb, which stands for X Virtual Frame Buffer. It's just a X server that uses a block of memory for display and no GPU at all. Try something like this:

```
mkdir -p $HOME/fb
Xvfb :2 -screen 0 1280x1024x24 -fbdir $HOME/fb &
sleep 3 # wait a bit
cudamat -display :2
```